# converting bat to shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have source of batch files which i need to convert to into shell script,i have do
converted most of the code but got stuck with the following code because i could'nt find any shell equivalents for it online so anyone help me in converting the batch script

batch code needed to convert:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (..\..\..\..\res\devices\*.xml) DO set xmls=!xmls! %%i
set xmls=!xmls! ..\..\..\..\res\RuntimeCreatedParams.xml

perl ParamEnumGen.pl ParamIds %xmls%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
 set xmls=!xmls! ...
```

is concatenation operator, then for loop would translate as

```
for i  in ../../../../res/devices/*.xml 
do 
   xmls="$xmls $i"
done

xmls="$xmls ../../../../res/RuntimeCreatedParams.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Archemar for helping me out